# How to find a specific kernel version in the Github repository?

Tags: linux, kernel, git, repository

I'm trying to get the Linux 4.14.85 kernel, for a [problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94808/raspi-config-is-not-working-after-installing-xenomai-on-raspberry-pi-3) I've posted before, related to Xenomai.

I see [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) that there is a branch for [4.14.y](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.14.y), but there are no tags to find which commit corresponds to the 4.14.85 version. Basically, I'm following the instructions provided [here](https://lemariva.com/blog/2018/07/raspberry-pi-xenomai-patching-tutorial-for-kernel-4-14-y) but I want to use the most up-to-date versions.

How can I find the appropriate commit to revert to it? Where should I look for it?

I will appreciate any tips or help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

An easier way to achieve this is to use `git log --follow Makefile` and from there scroll until you find the version you desire.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The only way I managed to find the commit was by manually scrolling through branch `rpi-4.14.y`'s commits until I got the correct one. The `Makefile` indicates the commit's version, patch level, and sublevel. With that information, I found it in [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commits/rpi-4.14.y?after=877656cd145497db7c09a7de06ea85db98bd72a3+839) page and here is [the commit for 4.14.85](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/862e7aaa90f63b1e3e3ab498dc3a3ac9a011b8d0).

Comment: `git log -S 'SUBLEVEL = 85' rpi-4.19.y` should also show you a list of commits with that patch number

Comment: Thanks @user60561, I tried this but I didn't get any results back. The terminal just stays idle.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://GitHub.com/hexxeh/rpi-firmware and look at the commits.

The last commit @ 4.14.85 is eefe4b161f5e9730183c8dc1605e14c85b15cf51

So that gives you a commit id to use with the rpi-update script.

Run `PRUNE_MODULES=1 rpi-update eefe4b161f5e9730183c8dc1605e14c85b15cf51 && reboot` and you'll be back on the kernel from Dec 5, 2018.

I won't ask why the stable 4.14.98 kernel you'd get with `apt update; apt install raspberrypi-kernel` isn't working for you because I guess you have a sound reason for reverting to something historic.

Comment: Hi @Dougie, thank you very much for your answer. Will getting it from https://github.com/hexxeh/rpi-firmware still allow me to patch the kernel with ipipe?

Comment: I tried this method, but I couldn't find the source files inside the Raspberry Pi (which I would need to patch the kernel with Xenomai). Instead, I am following the instructions in the [Raspberry Pi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) to build the kernel.

Comment: There's another script rpi-source which will pull the matching source tree for you. https://github.com/notro/rpi-source