# Building an old kernel is not possible because the arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/ directory does not exist

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation, device-tree, repository

I've been trying to build a kernel from the 4.14.85 version. I followed the instructions from the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) but instead of using the latest version you can find in [the repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) I reverted patches so that I ended up with the 4.14.85 version.

After reverting the patches, I just followed the instructions given in the official documentation, but at the very last step

```
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* mnt/fat32/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README mnt/fat32/overlays/
```

I cannot do this because the `/overlays` directory does not exist.

Are there any workarounds to this problem? I see that with more recent versions of the kernel, the `/overlays` directory does not exist, at least not in the same location.

Comment: With what version of Raspbian did you start off on your SD-card? Can you add the exact error message that does not allow you to finish the process from the tutorial?

Comment: Use https://github.com/notro/rpi-source to get the source tree that matches your kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94808/raspi-config-is-not-working-after-installing-xenomai-on-raspberry-pi-3/95208#95208) the solution I found to building the 4.14.85 kernel was to simply clone the Raspberry Pi Linux repository with

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch rpi-4.14.y https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
```

and then apply the incremental kernel patches in reverse, until reaching the 85-86 patch.

```
patch -R -p1 < ../patches-linux/patch-4.14.85-86
```